# How to send/include CSRF Token in spring-form JSP Tag Library

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following snippet Spring form with enabled `csrf()` in my config :

```
<form:form action="save" method="post" modelAttribute="book" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">

  --

  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form:form>
```

when I submit i get error `Invalid CSRF token found`.

I have already try some custom below :

1. With add token like `action="save?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"` to form action attribute, but my ModelAttibutes return NULL in my controller.
2. With remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute, token invalid solve and Model attribute have appropriate value except my byte[] field and also I get error `...is not a multipart request`

**Web MVC Config Snippet :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("me.ariphidayat.lib")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
  }

  ...

  @Bean
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

**Web Security Config Snippet :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses =
   me.ariphidayat.lib.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  ....

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
            .and().logout()
                .permitAll()
            .and().csrf()
            .and().rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
            .and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedExceptionHandler);
  }
}
```

**P.S. :** Previously, I have tested this with disable `csrf()` in my config and no issues.

Comment: Are you using Java config for Spring? If so you need the annotation `@EnableWebSecurity` to your config class: the token should then be auto generated when using <form:form/>. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token

Comment: Thank you @alan-hay , I have already added it to my config, but still get same error. have you any ideas?

Comment: @alan-hay, already added

Comment: Try adding:
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />

Inside your form element on page.